# Galaxy S6 edge touchable area

Tags: android, touchscreen, samsung-galaxy

My Android app uses `landscape` orientation and has a button at the very bottom of the screen. The display of `Galaxy S6 edge` is curved at edges and those edges barely respond to touch. So the button in my app can't be pressed on this device.

Is it possible to set touchable area to the whole screen including edges?